# ASP.NET 2.5 prefixing ctl00 and ASP.NET 4 not prefixing ctl00

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know why ASP.NET 4 has dropped the `ctl00` prefix on ASP controls?

Is there a setting I have missed?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In ASP.NET 4.0, they've introduced support for cleaner HTML syntax.  You can read about it [at Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx). If you want the classic model for Client IDs, you can adjust your web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" />
```

And that'll make upgrading your application easier. You can change this per control (and per page) by using the `Control.ClientIDMode` property, which can also be set in the web config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages clientIDMode="AutoID|Predictable|Static|Inherit" />
```

`AutoID` renders the controls with the classic ASP.NET 2.0 model.

Comment: In my case, it is probably special but for all those that tried this method and didn't work for the first time try also put the clientIDMode attribute in at the same time. <configuration><system.web>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">

Answer (score 1):

As far as i remember its up to ASP.NET to decide which prefix to use.
Its a bad practice to reference on the controls with hardcoded id value.

You should use ClientId property that will always generate you proper Id:

```
<td class="tmarg10" style="width: 150px">
    <label for="<%=txtName.ClientID %>">
        Name of the mall group :</label>
</td>
<td class="tmarg10">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Columns="90" /> <br />
</td>
```

In the example above, its calculating proper ID of the textbox and putting it into label attribute. In this way you will no more worry about keeping the same id of the control.

Answer (score 0):

Not a setting, but a decision by MS to simplify the way IDs of controls within containers are transformed to the client.

Here is a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) by Scott Guthrie explaining the changes.  The reasoning behind it:

> Clean, Standards-Based, CSS-Friendly Markup

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add 'ct100' prefix to your control's IDs, add Master page to your WebPage. But how said above, try to avoid using hardcode with controls ids in your sources and read Metthew's comments for generation custom ID