# textbox or any control id keep on changing, why?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

For my textbox, the following id generated on my local.

```
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucLogin1_txtUserName
```

When I hosted on IIS, the following id got generated.

```
ContentPlaceHolder1_ucLogin1_txtUserName
```

How can I get the textbox id? Don't reply answer as use `ClientID`, cos now I'm using external javascript file. It wont support `ClientID`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437717/asp-net-2-5-prefixing-ctl00-and-asp-net-4-not-prefixing-ctl00).

Comment: I don't know about others, but your question is not clear to me. Please provide more info

Answer (score 7):

If you're using ASP.NET 4.0 you can set [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) of the textbox to `Static` and its id always will be the same.

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: thanks all guys.. i revert back from js file to code inside my form.

Answer (score 2):

you could use that jquery

```
var clientId =$('input[id*="txtUserName"]').attr("id");
```

remember;
'input[id*="txtUserName"]' select all input element which is id  has got "txtUserName".

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ClientID, but what you can do is use a small bit of javascript on your page to set a variable to the passed ClientID for use with your external script.

Failing that if your using version 4 of the .Net Framework you can set ClientIDMode to Static so you have control over the ID Generation. See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There're a lot of ways to solve that, but one that'd be quick to implement is **just add an unique CSS class to this TextBox**.

That'd allow you to retrieve this TextBox in client-side by its CSS class by using some JavaScript client framework like jQuery:

`$("input.MyTextBoxCssClass")`

Another approach, if you are in ASP.NET 4.0 is the one suggested by **bniwredyc** in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

If you're targetting to ASP.NET 4.0 you can use set ID explicitly. [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx) are examples of how it is done.

Another option would be to pass the TextBox ID to your javascript function as a parameter and use the "ClientID" method when calling the javascript function. [Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1522697.aspx/1) is a similiar question.

Answer (score 1):

You should select the textbox without using its ID. Try adding a class to the textbox and selecting that:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" CssClass="txtUserNameClass"/>
```