# ASP.NET ID Placeholder Name

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I moved some of my pages to a different server, the ASP.NET started rendering the controls ID without the master page placeholder. So, before it used to be rendered like this `ctl00_MainContent_control1` and now it is `MainContent_control1`. What could of caused this change and if there's a way to control it?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437717/asp-net-2-5-prefixing-ctl00-and-asp-net-4-not-prefixing-ctl00/4437786#4437786

Answer (score 1):

You have the right to determine clientid by using clientid attribute, check if this [**link**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) helps you: