# Selenium Code works in debug mode but fails in run mode

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

My code below is basically selecting the dropdown controls on the form. It works in debug mode but fails to select  the dropdown values in run mode. Dont know why this is happening. The browser i am using chrome

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_Contents_Contents_dropdownlistday"))).SelectByText("9");
                driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("option[value=\"9\"]")).Click();
                new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_Contents_Contents_dropdownlistmonth"))).SelectByText("May");
                driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("option[value=\"May\"]")).Click();
                new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_Contents_Contents_dropdownlistyear"))).SelectByText("2000");
                driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("option[value=\"2000\"]")).Click();
```

Comment: try using some wait...in debug mode u anyhow wait to move forward...so time might be a issue..

Comment: i tried putting wait and that isnt the issue. I have this same piece of code which works fine for another page

Comment: Another point to note is works fine in firefox

Comment: Is the main control list ID the same between debug and run mode? Is it  possible that in run mode you are using a different version of ASP.NET that removes the ct100_ prefix? ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437717/asp-net-2-5-prefixing-ctl00-and-asp-net-4-not-prefixing-ctl00 for more info on the ct100_prefix)

Comment: At runtime, the id generated is ctl00_ctl00_Contents_Contents_dropdownlistday.

Comment: is it got to do with setting focus on the control

Comment: can u provide the stacktrace on chrome run?

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the option from dropdown, no need to click on that option again.

try with below code.

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_Contents_Contents_dropdownlistday"))).SelectByText("9");
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_Contents_Contents_dropdownlistmonth"))).SelectByText("May");
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_Contents_Contents_dropdownlistyear"))).SelectByText("2000");
```

Comment: i removed the click no difference. Though it works on debug mode.

Comment: Finding it quite strange. It works in debug mode as well firefox run mode. Only fails in chrrome run mode

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your appium project before finding the element.It works for me

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Eg:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
((AndroidDriver)   driver).swipe(startx1,starty1,endx1,starty1,2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a very ordinary solution but try reloading the page before your action. It worked in a project of mine.