# Input Id Changed when deployed to derver in dotnet webforms

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my form I need to insert a button and in the code behind file I am calling that button click event. While calling the button click event I am using javascript.

But the problem is when I deployed into UAT the id got changed in the code behind file. For example:

> "Window.Opener.document.forms[0].ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_button_click();"

changes to

> "Window.Opener.document.forms[0].ContentPlaceHolder1_button_click();"

I used ASP controls for button with runat = "server".

Appreciate any help!
Thanks.

Comment: The answers on this question may provide you with some information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437717/asp-net-2-5-prefixing-ctl00-and-asp-net-4-not-prefixing-ctl00

Comment: This is default behaviour, that is why we use [ClientID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your information. Can anyone show me how can I use the ClinetID, I am not that familiar. I am using ASP button control. Please find the format of it.    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="Server" Text="OK" Onclick="btn1_Click" /> How Can I add ClientID here?? Can anyone help me out.

Comment: `var yourButton = document.getElementById('<%=btn1.ClientID%>');` This is the general usage of `ClientID`

Answer (score -1):

You can execute which ever function is not `undefined`

`(Window.Opener.document.forms[0].ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_button_click || Window.Opener.document.forms[0].ContentPlaceHolder1_button_click)();`